# How do you select individual bones in Weight Paint mode in Blender 2.91?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I've been working on a tutorial in Blender for low-poly modeling, but I am stuck trying to select a bone in weight paint mode. Whenever I try doing that, nothing happens. I've tried pressing SHIFT-LEFT CLICK, but nothing happens? What do I do?

Comment: SHIFT-LEFT CLICK should work if you point at a vertex that has at least two groups already. If you select the armature and then shift select the mesh before entering weight paint, and you are not in vertex mode, you can click the bones. You can select the appropriate vertex group in Properties window. It all works for me in 2.9.3 with RMB select enabled.

Comment: For me it works this way: Select the armature, Shift select the object, switch to Weight Paint mode, Ctrl left click to select the bone.

Comment: How do I point at a vertex with two groups?

Comment: moonboots, I've did what you've told me, but when I do it, I still can't select the bone.